# Derived Associations in .Net Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

I want to have a single table that represents a person and have a number of other tables (such as Student/Teacher) use the Person table to store information related to a person.  Unfortunately the entity framework doesn't seem to like it when I try to add an association between the Student or Teacher class and I don't understand why.  The Person table contains a column called ParentEntityID, which equals either a StudentEntityID or a TeacherEntityID.  In an ideal world I would like to be able to reference the Person table by going Student.Person.FirstName instead of Student.Entity.Person1.FirstName.  The error .Net returns when trying to connect the Student/Teacher table to the Person table is:

> Error 3007: Problem in Mapping
>   Fragments starting at lines 265, 289:
>   Non-Primary-Key column(s)
>   [ParentEntityID] are being mapped in
>   both fragments to different conceptual
>   side properties - data inconsistency
>   is possible because the corresponding
>   conceptual side properties can be
>   independently modified.

The actual database I am working with is a bit more complicated and has a number of tables connected to the Entity table, which makes my object model pretty ambiguous and was hoping to be able to clean it up a bit by using the entity framework.

I am not much of a database guru, normally I work on the front end...  Can what I want be done or is there a better solution?

I am using VB.Net 3.5 in a web application.

[alt text http://commonfish.com/images/2010-stackoverflow1.png](http://commonfish.com/images/2010-stackoverflow1.png)

---

### Update...

In an attempt to internalize the different types of relationships I can form, I have been playing with this simple example and have come up with the following possibilities:
[alt text http://commonfish.com/images/2010-stackoverflow2.png](http://commonfish.com/images/2010-stackoverflow2.png)

[alt text http://commonfish.com/images/2010-stackoverflow3.png](http://commonfish.com/images/2010-stackoverflow3.png)

And the reason why I cannot make an association between the Student and Address table is because that relationship is not enforced in the database.  If I wanted an association between these two tables I would need to re-think the design of my database.  Is that correct?  What I want to do is not supported by the Entity Framework?

Also, looking at [a page linked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee828425.aspx) from Mr. Pratt, it sounds like .Net 4 supports foreign key associations, which I think is what I am trying to do.  Am I interpreting that article correctly??

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting an error because entity framework wants just one relationship/navigation property to own or manage the 'ParentEntityID' property. If, for example, you were to set both the 'Teacher' and 'Student' navigation properties on a 'Person' entity, EF wouldn't know which one should 'win'.

Can a single 'Person' be both a 'Student' and a 'Teacher'? If not, I would suggest modeling this as both 'Student' and 'Teacher' entities inheriting from 'Person' via TPT (table-per-type) inheritance [(example)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716702.aspx).

Comment: I cannot connect them through inheritance because the Teacher/Student tables primary key is not linked to the Person's primary key, instead they are linked to the ParentEntityID in the Person table.  It is structured this way so that a Teacher/Student could also link to an Address, Phone, etc table through it's own EntityID.